# Parallel builds using identical json file

Tags: packer

I have a base AMI which contains java and tomcat (`ami-c1f3e7a6`). My application stack consists of 6 separate java apps based on my base AMI, and I am using packer to create the 6 separate AMIs. The ansible playbook `app_playbook.yml`downloads the war file from S3 straight into the tomcat/webapps directory. My packer JSON is:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "war_file": ""
    },
    "builders": [{
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "source_ami": "ami-c1f3e7a6",
        "instance_type": "t2.small",
        "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
        "ami_name": "app-{{user `war_file`}}-{{timestamp}}"
    }],
    "provisioners": [{
        "type": "ansible",
        "playbook_file": "ansible/app_playbook.yml",
        "extra_arguments": "--extra-vars 'war_file={{user `war_file`}}'"
    }]
}
```

At the command line I am doing:

```
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_1.war' tomcat.json
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_2.war' tomcat.json
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_3.war' tomcat.json
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_4.war' tomcat.json
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_5.war' tomcat.json
packer build -var 'war_file=release123/application_6.war' tomcat.json
```

I have been looking into packer's ability to perform parallel builds to speed up the build process but it looks like the provisioner is run against every builder, and I need a specific variable passed into each builder.

I know I could fork the bash commands to execute the builds in parallel, but I feel like there must be a "packer" way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Packer doesn't support running the same builder multiple times. If you want to do that you need to duplicate the builder section for your `amazon-ebs` builder and the provisioner section using `only`.

This is best done by preprocessing a snippet with some script to create the final template.

Comment: do you have an example of a script that would do the pre-processing?